# does javamail load attachments into memory before sending?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I need to create an email with an attachment that is composed on the fly. In my first draft of this, I built the attachment as a String. But at the code walkthru others pointed out that the string could be very large. It's normally a few thousand bytes but occassionally it could be megabytes. So they said I should write it line-by-line to a temporary file and then attach the file to the email. Otherwise, I might run out of heap space.

I'm wondering if this actually helps. If JavaMail reads the entire file into memory before sending, it would make no difference. And of course creating a temporary file introduces other annoyances, like finding a suitable directory to put it, making sure I have permissions, etc. But if instead Javamail reads the file in some modest-sized chunks, then it would avoid out-of-memory problems.

A side issue is: As I understand it, Javamail sends synchronously. So if I create the file, send it, and then delete the file, there shouldn't be a problem of deleting the file before it's actually done sending, right?

Comment: The JavaMail internals seem to be pretty good about streaming data instead of buffering it. There are a few cases where it buffers, but those are the exception rather than the rule. If you'd rather not step through the source code, a simple experiment would be to allocate 8 MB of heap to your java process and try sending a 10 MB file.

Comment: Oh and yes, it's safe to delete the file after immediately after calling the send method.

Comment: @dnault: Good point on the simple test. I'm usually quick to conduct an empirical test rather than ponder philosophically, but for some reason I had a brain freeze and didn't think of this easy experiment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a DataHandler implementation, yes you can stream it. We do it all the time

```
            MimeBodyPart mbp2 = new MimeBodyPart();
            //  attach the file to the message
            mbp2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fids[i]));
            mbp2.setFileName(fids[i].getName());
```

Where fids[i] in this example was our own implementation of the DataSource interface

```
public abstract interface javax.activation.DataSource {

  // Method descriptor #4 ()Ljava/io/InputStream;
  public abstract java.io.InputStream getInputStream() throws java.io.IOException;

  // Method descriptor #8 ()Ljava/io/OutputStream;
  public abstract java.io.OutputStream getOutputStream() throws java.io.IOException;

  // Method descriptor #10 ()Ljava/lang/String;
  public abstract java.lang.String getContentType();

  // Method descriptor #10 ()Ljava/lang/String;
  public abstract java.lang.String getName();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But the intent of my question wasn't, "Can I use a file as an attachment?", but, "What happens in memory when I do?" i.e. does JavaMail load the whole thing into memory and then send it, or does it read the file in small chunks to send?

Comment: It reads it as a Stream. It does not buffer it in memory. To prove this, attach say 100 MB attachment in a 64 MB JVM.... no OOM. (I can tell you that I've done this test with JavaMail 1.4.several, but if you want to prove it (a good and worthy goal), it's easy to do so - you are armed with everything you need.

Answer (score 2):

Message created as described by MJB will be sent as an *attachment*, and I doubt that's the way you wanted it. This one is simpler and sends the message from the file as the body:

```
File file = new File("huge-message.txt");
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
msg.setFrom(...);
msg.setRecipient(...);
msg.setSubject(...);
msg.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(file)));
```

Comment: Actually in my present case I wanted it to be an attachment: We are attaching a report to an email. We want the email to simply say "Report XXX attached", then the user has the option to save the report file.

Comment: Your point is valid (and in fact our code supports large text bodies this way too) - I was just keeping to problem space of question. Voting you up because it's a good addition